Make a CommonJS module in random folder use the node_modules of the main module
I have the following two JS files:
/folderA/a.js
require('/folderB/b.js');

/folderB/b.js
require('ws');

The ws module is located in /folderA/node_modules/ws, hence the b.js fails to find it.
I was able to fix this by prefixing the ws in b.js like this:
require(require.main.path + '/node_modules/ws')

I'm wondering though can I make the b.js use the main module (a.js) paths to look for modules? So I can resolve the ws module from b.js without prefix.
Maybe there's a way to tell NodeJS where to look for modules when loading module b.js.
